# Modifying Python 3.6.4 list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have 2 lists:

```
L1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
L2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

I need my result to look like this:

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4']
```

I used a for loop, but I can't seem to get it right. This is what I did:

```
L3 = []
L1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
L2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
for i in range(len(L1)):
     L3 += L1[i] + L2[i]
print(L3)
```

My results end up looking like:

```
['a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '3', 'd', '4']
```

And that's all I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

The `zip` function produces an iterator that returns tuples from each of its arguments in sequence:

```
L3 = [x + y for x, y in zip(L1, L2)]
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 4):

`L3 += L1[i] + L2[i]` is equivalent to `L3.extend(L1[i] + L2[i])`

`L1[i] + L2[i]` is a string like 'a1'. `extend` expects an iterable, and it will append each of its elements to the list. So, it iterates over your 'a1' string and appends to the list the elements 'a' and '1'.

You want to `append` the string instead:

```
L3.append(L1[i] + L2[i])
```

As noted by Mark Tolonen,

```
L3 += [L1[i] + L2[i]]
```

also works. It is equivalent to `L3.extend([L1[i] + L2[i]])`, so for example `L3.extend(['a1'])`. In this case, `extend` will append the only element of the list it receives as parameter, 'a1', to L3.

Comment: @MarkTolonen That's right, I added it to the answer.

Comment: While it is true that `L3 += [L1[i] + L2[i]]` also works, I would argue that it is less clear than `L3.append(L1[i] + L2[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the `+=` operation to `.append`:

```
for i in range(len(L1)):
    L3.append(L1[i] + L2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L3 = []
L1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
L2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
for i in range(len(L1)):
     L3.append(str(L1[i])+str(L2[i]))
print(L3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer using list comprehension:

`L3 = [L1[i]+L2[i] for i in range(len(L1))]`